# How to toggle class "open", "closed" on an array in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

To get a better idea what i'm doing look here for my previous code that i try to make a little better >>[Codepen](http://codepen.io/motion_max/pen/gPXPVj)

I want to have an array that i fill up with all the `id's` that i try to animate and with one function toggle the classes `.open` `.closed` on every `id` in the array.

so on an click add `.open` to `#Hamburger, #Navigation, #Black-filter`. and one second click remove `.open` and add `.closed` for those `id's`.

because i'm still learning javascript i want it to work in vanilla javascript so i understand the basics before im going on with jquery.

```js
var hamburger = document.getElementById('Hamburger');
var navigation = document.getElementById('Navigation');
var blackFilter = document.getElementById('Black-filter');
var isOpen = true; // true or false

var animation = [h, s, b]; // #H #S #B
var open = "open"; // .open
var closed = "closed"; // .closed



function trigger() {
  if (isOpen === true) {
    animation.classList.add(open); // add .open to all id's
    animation.classList.remove(closed); // remove .closed from all id's
  } else {
    animation.classList.add(closed);
    animation.classList.remove(open);
  }
  isOpen = !isOpen; // toggles true to false
}

hamburger.addEventListener('click', trigger, false); // onclick toggle class
blackFilter.addEventListener('click', trigger, false); // onclick toggle class
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}
#Hamburger {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
}
#Hamburger.open {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#Hamburger.closed {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Navigation {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
}
#Navigation.open {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#Navigation.closed {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Black-filter {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
}
#Black-filter.open {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#Black-filter.closed {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="Hamburger"></div>
  <div id="Navigation"></div>
  <div id="Black-filter"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh my god! Please change your variable names. So much extra work decrypting your code because of the names.

Comment: please provide a minimal example (your css is not relevant). Also show some evidence of trying to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: Have you even looked at the console?

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe hope this is better^

Comment: @dan-man i have ben trying to figure it out for two days [attempt #4](http://codepen.io/motion_max/pen/JGrwxE?editors=011) i wouldn't ask here if i could do it myself.

Comment: You know that at the top you have set `var open` twice - once as a boolean variable and then a second time as a string variable? (Added: Well done for correcting).

Comment: @Rounin thanks didn't notice when i edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
var isOpen = true;

var hamburger = document.getElementById('Hamburger');
var navigation = document.getElementById('Navigation');
var blackFilter = document.getElementById('Black-filter');


var animatable = [hamburger, navigation, blackFilter];
var openClass = "open"; // .open
var closedClass = "closed"; // .closed



function trigger() {
    if (isOpen) {
        animatable.forEach(function (element) {
            element.classList.add(openClass);
            element.classList.remove(closedClass);
        });
    } else {
        animatable.forEach(function (element) {
            element.classList.add(closedClass);
            element.classList.remove(openClass);
        });
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
}

hamburger.addEventListener('click', trigger, false); 
blackFilter.addEventListener('click', trigger, false);
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeradG)

Comment: Is the behavior in the demo link I have placed what you are trying to go for?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that need improvement.

First of all you are naming you variables rather poorly. Which is actually already one of your problems, first you say that

```
var b = document.getElementById('B');
```

and then later

```
var b = "closed";
```

So this needs to be fixed, use variable names that are descriptive so you will know what you are talking about when.

Last but not least you are trying to change the elements of that array a, not the array itself. So you need to access the elements by themselves, set their classes and then you are good to go e.g.:

```
for( var index in a ) {
    if ( open === true ) {
        a[index].classList.add(b);
        a[index].classList.remove(c);
    } else {
        a[index].classList.add(c);
        a[index].classList.remove(b);
    }
    open = !open;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ou don't need "open" AND "close" classes, only one would clearly simplify your code (and there is the "default" state).

Then, add a class for all your buttons, the easily manipulate them in JS and CSS (here the class ".btn");

```js
// Directly get on array (a NodeList more precisely)
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

function toggleClass() {
  // Loop to add or remove (toggle) the the '.open' class 
  for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].classList.toggle('open');
  }
}

// Loop to add event listener to all buttons
for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', toggleClass, false);
}
```

```css
.btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.btn.open {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#Hamburger { background: red; }
#Navigation { background: blue; }
#Black-filter { background: green; }
```

```html
<div id="Hamburger" class="btn"></div>
<div id="Navigation" class="btn"></div>
<div id="Black-filter" class="btn"></div>
```

This is already way simpler. But you should have a parent element holding the opened/closes state, so you wouldn't loop in an array.

```js
// Only need to manipulate one DOM node
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

function toggleClass() {
  menu.classList.toggle('open');
}

menu.addEventListener('click', toggleClass, false);
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}
.btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.menu.open > .btn {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#Hamburger { background: red; }
#Navigation { background: blue; }
#Black-filter { background: green; }
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <div id="Hamburger" class="btn"></div>
  <div id="Navigation" class="btn"></div>
  <div id="Black-filter" class="btn"
</div>
```

Comment: what you are saying is correct and to make it less complicated only use the toggle state on the parent and let css do the work. but one thing that's not correct is dat i only need one class. i need two because of the keyframes i'm going to use, so i dont want it to animate when the page loads.

Answer (score -2):

Your event listener gets the event as the 1st argument. Use it to decide what to do:

```
function trigger(event) {// use event.target ... }
```

Comment: please explain why the -1!